# Testing itms-app://itunes.app.com/ links for unpublished application

Tags: ios, itunes, sharing, uiactivityviewcontroller

There are many answers explaining how to create a link to the app in the iTunes store:

> itms-app://itunes.apple.com/app/id{APPID}

My application is sending out an email via the sharing functionality in iOS7 (UIActivityViewController) which includes the above URL.

If the application has never been published before, clicking on the above link in the email on the iPhone device (the Simulator doesn't have the iTunes application) opens iTunes as expected but nothing is displayed.

How can I verify **before publishing the initial version** of my app that my **iTunes link is indeed correct**?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to verify, just hope that it will work, really. What I do is plug in the id of one of my existing apps during testing to make sure that works, then before publishing I grab the actual id from itunesconnect, paste it in, and submit!

Comment: This is my first app, so I don't have an id already. Is there a way to get the id of another app?

Comment: @PhilippSchmid Yup: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-exchange/id871299723?mt=8 it's after id but before the ?